# What can I do if I want to work the kick pedal on Bass Drum with my heel?

Tags: drums, cajon

I'm a casual (basement band, i.e., not gigging) drummer and I've been thinking of **replacing the kick pedal on the bass drum of my (typical 5-piece) drum set with a cajon pedal so I can work the kick with my heel** rather than the ball of my foot (by rotating the cajon pedal 180 degrees).

I'm wondering if a cajon pedal's cable mechanism can withstand being used this way.

Has anyone tried this? **Or is there a better way to work a kick pedal with my heel?**

Comment: I can't answer your question but interestingly I saw a band last week playing out live and the drummer replaced the kick drum in his kit with a cajon.  He said it took up much less space on a small stage and he liked the flat surface on top so he could set his drink or phone on it when not playing.  It sounded fine in the mix.

Answer (score 2):

Just following up here. I bought a cajon pedal from my local drum shop for $160 with their promise that I could return it within two weeks if it didn't work out.

Well, it didn't work out. There were two issues: first, the height at the heel was uncomfortably high, and it was a lot of work from a sitting position (it might work from a standing position); and second, the angle of the pedal tended to push my foot forward so it was a struggle to maintain my heel's position.

It's possible some fine-tuning of the pedal mechanics and a bit of practice would have made this workable. But my sense of it was, there's a reason kick pedals are oriented the way they are, and I should get used to it.

Besides, I can get a pretty decent pedal for less than the cajon pedal cost.

Comment: Absolutely agree, the cajon mechanism might accommodate the most basic of beat keeping responsibilities. For the most part, however, you will want to utilize a regular kick pedal and modify your playing style to accommodate both your musical needs and your comfort level.